# Remove hyphens from a factor variable

Tags: r

I have variable responses that look like this 12-345-0678.  I am trying to remove the hyphens with gsub but it doesn't seem to be working.  I think this may be because although this is numeric it is classified as a factor.  I have tried converting from a factor first but it still has not worked.

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4)
Variable1 <- c("12-345-0567","12-345-04859","12-345-05278", "12-345-07846")

df = data.frame(ID,Variable1)
```

I want Variable1 to look like this

```r
ID  Variable1

1   123450567           
2   1234504859          
3   1234505278          
4   1234507846
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's helpful to see what didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_remove_all` from `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(Variable1 = str_remove_all(Variable1, '-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be something else going on - perhaps you didn't use the right gsub code. I ran the following:

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4)
Variable1 <- c("12-345-0567","12-345-04859","12-345-05278", "12-345-07846")
Variable1 <- as.factor(Variable1)
Variable1 <- gsub(x = Variable1, pattern = "-", replacement = "")
df = data.frame(ID,Variable1)
```

And received from the console:

```
  ID  Variable1
1  1  123450567
2  2 1234504859
3  3 1234505278
4  4 1234507846
```

Good luck!

Comment: Another way of using `gsub` is to simply `df$Variable1 <- gsub("-","",df$Variable1)`. It works also with `factors`